# Fourier transform of a double integral

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, multiple-integral

Fourier transform of
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\iint K(|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|)n_1(\mathbf{r})n_1(\mathbf{r}')\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'
$$
is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int K(\mathbf{q})|n(\mathbf{q})|^2\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}
$$

where
$$
n(\mathbf{q})=\int n_1(\mathbf{r})\exp(-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}
$$
$$
n_1(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int n(\mathbf{q})\exp(i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}
$$

It seems like to use the Fourier transform of the convolution...
And not sure how to deal with the absolute in function *K*.

---

Suddenly, almost solved and understood.

Step 1: Insert
$$
n_1(\mathbf{q})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int n(\mathbf{q})\exp(-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}
$$
into the first Eq.

Step 2: Change the variable
$$
\mathbf{q}\rightarrow-\mathbf{q}
$$

Then

$$
-\frac{1}{2}\iint K(|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|)n_1(\mathbf{r}')\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int n(\mathbf{q})\exp(i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\iint K(|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|)n_1(\mathbf{r}')\int n(\mathbf{q})\exp(-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \left[\iint K(|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|)n_1(\mathbf{r}')\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'\exp(-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\right]n(\mathbf{q})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \left[K(\mathbf{q})n(\mathbf{q})\right]n(\mathbf{q})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int K(\mathbf{q})|n(\mathbf{q})|^2\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}
$$

But, why the absolute can be ignored?

Comment: @Semiclassical Sorry. This is my first time writing. It's corrected. And I found my answer except to be sure to understand about "absolute."